# Dataflow - distinct got stuck with 3MB of data and kills throughput

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have python dataflow job that reads data from pubsub, extract some user information, window them into 5min timeframe, distinct and then do some more processing.

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        users = (p
            | "ReadEvents" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.subscription, with_attributes=False)
            | "ExtractUsers" >> beam.ParDo(ExtractUserIdHash())
            | beam.ParDo(AddTimestampFn())
            | beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(300, 0), allowed_lateness=Duration(seconds=3*24*60*60))
            | beam.Distinct())
```

This works fine in dev environment where I had about 5000 elements in pubsub, but when I deploy this to production environment, it got stuck. Looking at graph (screenshot below), it seems like

1. `Distinct` takes very long time
2. throughput remains very low

[image]

Looking at CPU utilization, looks like lots of workers are created and using lots of CPUs (and recreated for some reason).

[image]

My questions are:
A) It seems there is only 3MB of data coming into `Distinct`. Why it takes so long to process and use so much CPUs?
B) Why input throughput is so low? Even if `Distinct` is slow, can I somehow instruct dataflow to read more data so we can catch up with backlog?

EDIT:
Here are some flags I use that might be relevant

```
    --worker_machine_type e2-medium \
    --max_num_workers 10 \
```

Comment: Have you tried to scale up the max amount of the workers and storage capacity as per the suggestion [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#tsg-resource-exhausted-no-disk-space)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out worker is running out of disk space and restarting by itself. My `ParDo` install file (ML model) that is about 50MB in size. It seems dataflow VM uses Docker to run multiple workers, and new workers get recreated continuously (my observation from docker ps).

When I ssh into worker harness vm with

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone us-east1-c <name of VM like myjob-abc-harness-abc>
```

and did

```
# list of containers
docker ps --no-trunc

# sudo tail -f /var/lib/docker/containers/<container_id>/<container_id>-json.log
```

I saw a lot of log like `no space left on device`

I tried running job again with `disk_size_gb` parameter
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options

I specify 250GB (it seems 30GB was default for my case) and then job started working file for about an hour, then started failing again. I also tried to writing temporary folder `tempfile.gettempdir()` but I guess tmp file is not cleared when container stopped so it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Distinct operation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.25.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/util.html#Distinct) from the python source is:

```
  pcoll
  | 'ToPairs' >> Map(lambda v: (v, None))
  | 'Group' >> CombinePerKey(lambda vs: None)
  | 'Distinct' >> Keys())
```

The CombinePerKey will be doing a shuffle, which in this case will be per key-window. If your backlog contains many windows then this could indicate a heavy shuffle stage.

Consider making use of the [Streaming Engine](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#streaming-engine) if possible.

If not, then the shuffle will be done on the workers and if the issue is that the pipeline is I/O bound, then adding larger disks, or SSD disks will provide more I/O  [Disk Info](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdspecs).